# How to change a string to NaN when applying astype?

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a column in a dataframe that has integers like: `[1,2,3,4,5,6..etc]`

My problem: In this field one of the field has a string, like this: `[1,2,3,2,3,'hello form France',1,2,3]`

the Dtype of this column is object.

I want to cast it to float with `column.astype(float)` but I get an error because that string.

The columns has over 10.000 records and there is only this record with string.   How can I cast to float and change this string to NaN for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'all_nums':range(5),
    'mixed':[1,2,'woo',4,5],
})

df['mixed'] = pd.to_numeric(df['mixed'], errors='coerce')
df.head()
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]